# O uso da vírgula está correto?

Tags: vírgula

Está correta o uso da vírgula nesta frase?

> A Bolsa de Valores de São Paulo garantiu,
> a bancos e corretoras, o pagamento de
> compra de ações.

Answer (score 2):

Está correto porque há uma inversão da ordem dos elementos da frase. Em geral, temos: sujeito + verbo + objeto direto + objeto indireto + complementos.

Nesse caso, talvez por estilo ou para dar ênfase a quem seria dado garantias, colocou-se o objeto indireto a frente.

Answer (score 0):

Correto. O uso da vírgula neste caso é facultativo. Não se usa vírgula para separar sujeito do predicado e antes de "e"(mas há excessões específicas). Isso sao regras básicas do uso da vírgula.

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor qual regra que é facultativa nesse caso?